# call javascript alert from java class

Tags: java, javascript

How to call javascript alert from java class

Comment: I think you need to understand what [Greg Hewgill wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java/245068#245068) to the question [What’s the difference between JavaScript and Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java):
*Java and Javascript are similar like Car and Carpet are similar.*

Comment: Your question cannot be intelligently answered in its current form. As Wazzy said, *please elaborate*. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: The complete lack of context here means that any answer could only ever be speculative. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for a message box similar to the Javascript alert() box? Then use

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't know for sure, but if you want to make a Java Applet and Javascript interact, try these:

[Java-to-Javascript Communication](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html)

[Java - Javascript interaction](http://www.raditha.com/java/javascript.php)